# du seiest vs du seist?

Tags: grammatical-case, verb-usage

I'm just starting out in Deutsch, mostly on my own.

I was writing out verb tenses, when I came across "du seiest" and "du seist".

Both are listed under Konjunktiv I, Präsens.

What's the difference in meaning and usage, in German and hopefully English?

Thanks!

Comment: That question is far too broad. Any grammar will have long chapters about how subjunctive is used. On the other hand, _seist_ and _seiest_ are just minor variants without a difference in meaning.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language StackExchange. Feel free to take the [tour] or browse the [help]. Have fun :)

Comment: @chirlu That depends on your reading of the question. As you noted, the difference between *du seist* and *du seiest* is merely orthographic, so you gave a perfectly valid answer. However, if the question is actually about the general use of the Konjunktiv I, it is indeed far too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the two mentioned forms of *seist* und *seiest* have no difference in meaning. *Seiest* is IMHO an outdated form of *seist*.

While modern English has lost the difference in verb forms expressing the subjunctive and indicative, German has not. I agree with the comment on your question that any attempt to explain more would go too far.

Example:

**I thought you were older than your brother.**

*Ich dachte, du seist älter als dein Bruder*

**He said you were a policeman.**

*Er sagte, du seist Polizist.*

Comment: Just a comment that English does have rests of subjunctive mood, although it is used a bit differently from German subjunctive. First the use of *were* in first and 3rd person singular is subjunctive use, e.g. *If I were that stupid, I'd have to run away* (That case is rather similar to the German one, but only pertains to *to be*). In present tense, the subjunctive is identical to the infinitive (hence, it can typically only be distinguished in 3rd person singular, except with *to be*) and is used in constructions as *I demand that he leave* or *I insist that you be nice*.

Comment: To clarify: I was not trying to say English had no subjunctive form - It just normally happens to look identical to the indicative ;)

Comment: Thanks! I asked my German cousin, she said she uses seist these days because it's shorter and they're basically the same. :/ As an American in the public school system, I never learned parts of grammar beyond nouns and verbs for English... so you kinda lost me, but I get the general idea. Thanks!